# Exception handling within exception

Tags: python-3.x, exception, error-handling, try-catch

So I have following two different try-except blocks, where I do not understand the output and I believe it is because of Exceptions within except blocks. Even though I found a few questions with a similar title, they did not help me answering my question.

First block:

```
try:
    try:
        raise IndexError
        x = 5/0
    except ArithmeticError:
        print("1")
        print("2")
    except IndexError:
        print("3")
    finally:
        print("4")
except:
    print("5")                #Output: 3 4
```

Since we caught the IndexError, why does the last exception ***5***? 
(*I do understand that the* `raise IndexError` *is caught by the second except and we get the* ***3***, *and since finally is always executed*, ***4*** *is printed out aswell*).

Second (related) Question:

```
try:
    try:
        x = 5/0
    except ArithmeticError:
        print("1")
        raise IndexError            # this is different this time!
        print("2")
    except IndexError:
        print("3")
    finally:
        print("4")
except:
    print("5")                      #Output: 1 4 5
```

How is it, that the `raise IndexError` does not execute the `print("3")` statement? And why do we get the 5 output this time, since we did not get it in the first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`except` will catch exceptions thrown in the `try`, but *not* in other sibling `except` blocks.  For any given `try` with multiple sibling `except` blocks, *one* of those `except` blocks will handle the exception.

In your first example `5` is not printed because the code within the outer `try` does not throw an exception.  An exception in the inner `try` is thrown, and is handled by one of the `except` blocks at that level.

In your second example `3` is not printed because the code in the `try` block does not throw an `IndexError`.  It throws an `ArithmeticError`, which is caught by the corresponding `except` block.  *That* block then also throws an exception, which exist the entire `try/except` structure and gets caught by a higher `except` block.

Comment: Oh I see I should pause it for today. Totally clear for the first example. But thanks alot for the explanation for the second example. Made it clear!